The Allowance Problem
Stan gets his allowance on the $15^{th}$ day of every month, he gets $1$ dollar if its a Monday, $2$ dollars if it’s a Tuesday, $3$ dollars if its a Wednesday and so on $7$ dollars if it’s a Sunday. Then on a particular $15^{th}$ of a random month, find the expected value of the money Stan will be receiving.
This is what I have done (and I know this is wrong):
$$P(\text{Getting allowance on any specific day}) = \frac{1}{7}.$$
So, expected value of allowance = $\sum_{i=1}^7\frac{i}{7}=4.$
I know this is wrong because probaility of a day being specific day need not be same for everyday (there might be more sundays than more mondays (like it is possible for any pair of days) which depends on which year in this is happening ). So, $P(\text{Getting allowance on any specific day}) \neq \frac{1}{7}$.
Even though I know I'm wrong, I cant understand what to do next. Can you please help me?

Personally, I would look at years and leap years mod $7$

You can put ordinary text into a mathematical expression like this: $P(\text{event occurrence}) = 1/2$ yields $P(\text{event occurrence}) = 1/2$. You can click "Edit" on your post (and then "Cancel") to see how I applied this to your post in context.

@Brain Tung Thank you for that!

A "random month" chosen from what population?
The Gregorian calendar works on a $400$-year cycle, comprising $146097$ days ($3$ less than the Julian calendar).  Since $146897$ is divisible by $7$, the
day of the week also repeats every $400$ years.  In $400$ years, or $4800$ months, the $15$'th of the month is Sunday $688$ times, Monday $684$ times, Tuesday $687$ times, Wednesday $685$ times, Thursday $685$ times, Friday $687$ times and Saturday $684$ times.  So if you know nothing about what year it is, or even what century, you can take the "random month" to be selected with equal probabilities from the $4800$ months in the $400$-year cycle, and the expected value is $(1 \times 684 + \ldots + 7 \times 688)/4800 = 2401/600 = 4.0016\ldots$.
Of course, if you do know the century or the year, things are different. For example, in $2024$ the $15$'th was Tuesday, Wednesday and Saturday once each, Sunday, Thursday and Friday twice each, and Monday $3$ times, so the expected value, if you selected a random month in $2024$, would be $23/6 = 3.8333\ldots$. But in $2023$ it would have been $13/3 = 4.3333\ldots$.
